# Call to webservice in objective c

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, web-services

I want equivalent method for objective C from JAVA code

```
public static void post(URL url, byte[] msg, String user, String pass) throws Exception
{
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + makeAuth(user,pass));
    //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", msg.length + "");
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(msg);
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("\n*** POST results ***");
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    printResults(in);
    try {out.close();} catch (Exception whocares) {}
    try {in.close();} catch (Exception whocares) {}
}
```

Here is called the web service where uri is URL for webservice.
user and pass is username and password.

Can any one know how to call the same thing in objective c.

Comment: What class does the `post` method belong to? What sort of authentication (basic, digest, NTLM etc.) is being used to check username and passwerd? What happens to the result of the POST request? Is it discarded? Is this working Java code or something you made up?

Comment: Sorry that was the method call. I have updated with the method definition. Now Can you give me the code for iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it just as easily using foundation classes.

```
- (void)postUser:(NSString *)user andPass:(NSString *)pass toURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", makeAuth(user, pass)] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response from server: %@", responseString);
    [responseString release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) (as proposed by 0xJoKe) and implement it like this:

```
- (void)post:(NSData *)data toURL:(NSURL *)url username:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *) password
{
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUsername:username];
    [request setPassword:password];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml"];
    [request appendPostData:data];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSData *responseData= [request responseData];
    // do something with response
}
```

Note that I've used `NSData` instances instead of byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A easy to use and very powerful option is the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).
To send a POST-request, you should use [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) which makes it really easy for you to set variables, the username and the password you need to access the server.